# Sql Server use CONTAINS function as column in a select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

I am writing a select statement and I would like it to include in the list of columns a call to the CONTAINS function in sql server.

I want it to be something like this:

```
   SELECT  i.IncidentID, CONTAINS(sa.AddressStreet, 'asda') AS 'asda' FROM Incident i
            JOIN IncidentSubject isu ON isu.IncidentID = i.IncidentID
            JOIN SubjectAddress sa ON sa.SubjectID = isu.SubjectID
            WHERE i.Section <> 0 AND (i.Section & 255 <> 0)
```

But I get an error when using contains in the columns sections. With other functions such as LEN is works.

Comment: *"But I get an error when using contains in the columns sections."* You forgot to include said error. :) but why do you have `CONTAINS` in your `SELECT`? `CONTAINS` returns a boolean result; they can't be expressed in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: From [the MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): CONTAINS is a predicate used in the WHERE clause... A column is not a WHERE clause

Comment: What are you actually trying to get out of trying to use `CONTAINS` as a column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CONTAINS is a predicate used in the WHERE clause of a Transact-SQL SELECT statement to perform SQL Server full-text search on full-text indexed columns containing character-based data types.
It means, could not be used in SELECT. 
However, as I understand correctly you can use CharIndex

```
SELECT i.IncidentID, 
       CHARINDEX('asda', sa.AddressStreet)  'asda'
FROM Incident i
     JOIN IncidentSubject isu ON isu.IncidentID = i.IncidentID
     JOIN SubjectAddress sa ON sa.SubjectID = isu.SubjectID
WHERE i.Section <> 0
      AND (i.Section&255 <> 0);
```

See more on [CONTAINS (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [CHARINDEX (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

As JohnHC already pointed out CONTAINS is a predicate that can be used in WHERE clauses only.

You could try this instead

```
 SELECT  
   i.IncidentID, 
   CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('asda', sa.AddressStreet) > 0 THEN 'true' else 'false' end AS 'asda' 
FROM Incident i
JOIN IncidentSubject isu ON isu.IncidentID = i.IncidentID
JOIN SubjectAddress sa ON sa.SubjectID = isu.SubjectID
WHERE i.Section <> 0 AND (i.Section & 255 <> 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
SELECT
       i.IncidentID, 
       sa.AddressStreet [asda]
FROM Incident i
     JOIN IncidentSubject isu ON isu.IncidentID = i.IncidentID
     JOIN SubjectAddress sa ON sa.SubjectID = isu.SubjectID
WHERE i.Section <> 0
      AND (i.Section&255 <> 0)
      AND CONTAINS(sa.AddressStreet, 'asda');
```